# JQuery Resizable Touchscreen

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-mobile

i am using jQuery resizable method to resize the div, its working fine with mouse but on touchscreen its not working..it doesn't show the re-sizable cursor and doesnt resize with touch device. like android samsung tablet please let me how how to fix this.

plunker 
http://plnkr.co/edit/mU18FfjoXRHgRkzAvIcx?p=preview
please guide me how to proceed further on touch device.

```
<!doctype html>
```

Comment: Resizable is part of jQueryUI. Touchpunch tries to make jQueryUI compatible with touch devices, so give it a try: http://touchpunch.furf.com/

Comment: thanks, I tried the touchpunch and it did worked.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I tried touchpunch and it worked.

Here are the instructions from [their github page](https://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch):

> Just follow these simple steps to enable touch events in your jQuery
>   UI app:
>
> Include jQuery and jQuery UI on your page.
>
> ```
> <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
> <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.17/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
> ```
>
> Include Touch Punch after jQuery UI and before its first use.
>
> Please note that if you are using jQuery UI's components, Touch Punch
>   must be included after jquery.ui.mouse.js, as Touch Punch modifies its
>   behavior.
>
> ```
> <script src="jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
> ```
>
> There is no 3. Just use jQuery UI as expected and watch it work at the
>   touch of a finger.
>
> ```
> <script>$('#widget').resizable();</script>
> ```

Comment: thanks for your comment..i have updated the content. please increase the points now.